# Excel scatter plot with two x series and one y series

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

My data consists of a y value and the two x values that can be used as inputs to a quadratic equation to give the y value.  I'd like to plot them, ideally with separate colours for the positive and negative halves of the curve, on a scatter plot, but nothing I've tried has made more than half of it work at the same time.  Here's my data:

```
22  7.773592453 0.226407547
50  7.464101615 0.535898385
75  7.16227766  0.83772234
80  7.098386677 0.901613323
100 6.828427125 1.171572875
140 6.19089023  1.80910977
175 5.414213562 2.585786438
200 4           4
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a scatter plot graphic, Excel makes some assumptions about your data structure, but you can change that easily afterwards.

Here is a simple approach:

1. select the three columns and create a scatter plot. Don't worry that it seems all wrong.
2. single-click on any data point. In the formula bar, you will see the 'formula' that defines the plot. Example: `=SERIES(Sheet1!$A$1;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$100;Sheet1!$B$2:$B$100;1)`
3. You can now click in the formula bar, and change the parameters the way you want them:

   - first parameter defines the title (hard text or a cell, can be empty)
   - second parameter defines the X data (without header line)
   - third parameter defines the Y data (again without header line)
   - fourth parameter defines the logical number of the data, if you have multiple set, so for you it is 1 or 2 depending on which data set you select
4. Once you have adjusted the parameters to your liking, press return, and the plot will update.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense -- I was looking through the dialogs to find a way of changing the definition of the series, but this looks like it's a much more useful approach.